# Algolia Js Helper Facets

Tags: algolia

I have 3 columns:

```
name, status, date
```

I want to initialize all searches to something like

```
and (where status is 'a' orWhere status is 'b' orWhere status is 'c')
```

so when somebody makes a search on the name (attribute) it would use those filters. How do I do this search in algolia using the algoliasearchHelper(js)?

Is this what Facets are for, disjunctiveFacets?

Comment: What do you mean when you by adding the and before the parameters? Is it that you want to do whatever other parameters AND those that you have already set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you want to do `status is 'a' orWhere status is 'b' orWhere status is 'c'`, then disjunctiveFacets is the way to do using the [algoliaSearchHelper](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#disjunctive-facets)